# GMAIL: How do I not Top Post in Gmail Replies?

Tags: gmail

I am currently on a mailing list, and it appears that the gmail default is to "top-post", which upsets group users.  How do I turn this off?

Comment: Not really appropriate for stackoverflow though

Comment: Which stack is better?

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... 8 years since the last answer; things must have improved?

No - actually not! But here's how I manage it:

First, put your Gmail client in 'plain text' mode!

Then, after clicking the "Reply" button:

1. Scroll to the bottom of the message
2. Click the ellipsis `...` in the LLHC of the message to "Show trimmed content"
3. Then in the URHC of the message, click "Pop out reply"
4. In the popped-out reply frame, I remove the blank lines at the top, and the other rubbish, then drop to the bottom to add my reply.

This seems to beat mud-wrestling `mutt` config & the other gar-bage that you're put through trying to use an alternate client for Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

One shortcut is to select some text before hitting reply, it will do a partial quote and start your post below it.

Comment: @AkiRoss: It got moved into a lab because too many people were running into it unexpectedly. (Selecting text while reading it for no particularly strong reason, and without necessarily remembering afterwards, is apparently a fairly common user behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing a "select all" + page-down works quite right for me.

Answer (score -1):

The answer above (select some text) is quite helpful, but a more general one is "put the cursor where you should begin writing, before writing."  Neither GMail nor any other user-agent **understands** the text, so it cannot do the Right Thing.  **You** can edit and compose to make your point most effectively.

Read what you are writing, including quotations.  Would you understand your posting without unnecessary effort, if you had not written it but come across it in a search?  If the whole flows well, makes sense, and conveys your meaning, it is probably right.  If not, figure out why not and fix it.  That's why your machine has cursor keys.

Comment: Although I agree with you, the web based GMail client tries to hide the fact from you that you can indeed do bottom (or middle, or whatever) posting, as it actually hides the whole message under a dim ellipsis (…).

Comment: One thing is putting the cursor in the right place. Another is erasing the first few empty lines, cutting the signature, putting it on the bottom, and then putting the cursor where needed. Gets old very fast.

Comment: Hello, sorry if you didn't at the time, but please use comments for things like this.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, here is the answer, just delete the embedded previous messages from the reply hidden by the ...

See here

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]